# How do I use "spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config" to configure a parameter in the spring-boot application.yaml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I have the following...

```
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    region: us-east-2
    arn: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:...:secret:dev/.../...
```

I am trying to use the secrets there to configure my JPA. I have the following secrets in the secret listed...

- spring.datasource.url
- spring.datasource.username
- spring.datasource.password

How do I now inject these into the application.yml? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Updates**

So to clarify here is the structure of the secret

[image]

Also the deal is if I use the following...

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ...
    username: ...
    password: ...
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

It works great but I want those datasource properties injected from the secret. Then I would like the data source to connect per those settings.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you might have missed adding the `spring.config.import` option in the `application.yml` file.

Assuming you have created the following secrets:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret \ 
--name /secrets/database-secrets \ 
--secret-string "{\n    \"spring.datasource.url\": \"jdbc:h2:file:./h2.db\",\n    \"spring.datasource.username\": \"root\",\n    \"spring.datasource.password\": \"password\"\n}"
```

[image]

You would need to tell spring the namespace it needs to import from the `secrets manager`:

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import: aws-secretsmanager:/secrets/database-secrets?prefix=secrets. # <- DOT IS INTENTIONAL!
```

Then you should be able to reference the secrets inside the regular spring properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${secrets.spring.datasource.url}
    username: ${secrets.spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${secrets.spring.datasource.password}
```

For this to work you need the following dependencies:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
}

group = "org.carlspring.hello.world.spring.boot.aws.secretsmanager"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2022.0.3"
extra["springCloudAwsVersion"] = "3.0.1"

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:${property("springCloudAwsVersion")}"))
    implementation("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter")
    implementation("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager")
    //implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I've also prepared a simple hello world project which should be enough for you to checkout.

https://github.com/steve-todorov/spring-boot-aws-secrets-manager

You can also checkout the documentation here:

https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/index.html#spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager

Comment: So I think you are a little confused. I don't want to use it later in my code I just want to have it injected into the datasource so the connection works. I think you are pretty close with your spring config stuff I am just a little confused there. Let me add some additional detail to the question and maybe that will help.

Comment: Tried to add some more detail, thank you so much for your help but let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: @Jackie I've updated my answer with a working example. :)

Comment: I'll give you the 50 just for going the extra mile thanks! I will test and confirm it works!